# how can i solve this issue Click bug with an audio ProgressBar in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking the course to boost your website with JS

I created an audio player, which displays the elapsed time of the audio file when it starts playing.
with progress bar is displayed at 100% with the message "no reading"
From there I can position the "playhead" by clicking on the progress bar in order to start playback at half of the audio file for example.
So I end up with a progressbar filled to 50%

But if I click again on the progress bar to start a little later it is impossible because the area above 50% is no longer clickable ....
You can see my project on codePen with this link

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
   //Progress bar
function update(player) {
    var duration = player.duration;    // Durée totale
    var time     = player.currentTime; // Temps écoulé
    var fraction = time / duration;
    var percent  = Math.ceil(fraction * 100);
    document.querySelector('#progressTime').textContent = formatTime(time);// ajoute le temps
 
    var progress = document.querySelector('#progressBar');
     
    progress.style.width = percent + '%';
    progress.textContent = percent + '%';
}
 
//Afficher temps ecouler
function formatTime(time) {
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    var mins  = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
    var secs  = Math.floor(time % 60);
     
    if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
    }
     
    if (hours) {
        if (mins < 10) {
            mins = "0" + mins;
        }
         
        return hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs; // hh:mm:ss
    } else {
        return mins + ":" + secs; // mm:ss
    }
}
 
//Bar cliquable
// Recuperer les coordonée du curseur
function getMousePosition(event) {
    return {
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
    };
}
 
//Recuperer les coordonnée d'un elements
function getPosition(element){
    var top = 0, left = 0;
     
    do {
        top  += element.offsetTop;
        left += element.offsetLeft;
    } while (element = element.offsetParent);
     
    return { x: left, y: top };
}
 
// On clique sur la barre de progression
function clickProgress(idPlayer, control, event) {
    var parent = getPosition(control);    // La position absolue de la progressBar
    var target = getMousePosition(event); // L'endroit de la progressBar où on a cliqué
    var player = document.querySelector('#' + idPlayer);
   
    var x = target.x - parent.x;
    var wrapperWidth = document.querySelector('#progressBarControl').offsetWidth;
     
    var percent = Math.ceil((x / wrapperWidth) * 100);   
    var duration = player.duration;
     
    player.currentTime = (duration * percent) / 100;
}
```

Comment: Can you add codepen?

Comment: Where's the link?